# What is the production status of the Pipistrel Panthera as of March 2017?

Tags: new-airplane

What is the production status of the Pipistrel Panthera? They had plans to start production in 2016/2017 but nothing new has been published in the last two years.

Comment: Great question.  I have high hopes that it will be the much needed competitor to Cirrus.  It looks almost too good to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have more news on that next week from Sun 'n Fun 2017.  Pipistrel will be an exhibitor at the show and may have a Panthera prototype on display.

Currently the Panthera is planned to be released as an experimental kit and may be type certified at some point in the future.

I know the program has suffered some setbacks, including an increase of empty weight by some 200 lbs.  New aircraft development is never fast nor without complications.

The Panthera does look intriguing - 200 KIAS on 10 GPH with good, stable flight characteristics and modern avionics, BRS parachute, etc.  I want to take it for a demo flight when production examples become available.